# How do conveniently control where description text starts?

Tags: lists, indentation, description

Consider a description list in which the body of a description is indented by some amount (`\leftmargin` I think). There are 3 obvious options for where the text of the first line of the description can begin:

1. At some fixed space from the end of the described term. (This is the default behavior.)
2. At `\leftmargin` on the same line as the described term, if possible, or on the next line otherwise.
3. Always at `\leftmargin` on the line below the defined term.

Here are option 1 and two ways of effecting option 3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\filledterm}[1]{%
  #1%
  \setlength{\mylength}{\textwidth-\widthof{#1}}%
  \hspace{\mylength}
}
\begin{document}
Plain vanilla:
\begin{description}
\item[One] \lipsum[4]
\item[And another one]  \lipsum[4]
\end{description}
With \verb|\mbox{}\\|:
\begin{description}
\item[One]\mbox{}\\  \lipsum[4]
\item[And another one]\mbox{}\\  \lipsum[4]
\end{description}
With filling:
\newlength{\mylength}
\begin{description}
\item[\filledterm{One}] \lipsum[4]
\item[\filledterm{And another one}] \lipsum[4]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Option 2 is a bit trickier, I guess I would need some kind of conditional in there.

Anyway, my question is - how can I actually *avoid* using these ugly hacks in each list separately? I want to be able to have some of my description lists behave one way, and others a different way. Do I need to patch the \item command somehow? ... but if I do that, it will effect all lists. I suppose I could use an `\itemwrapper` command in the relevant lists instead of `\item`, but I'd actually rather avoid that.

What would be a convenient-to-use (and hopefully elegant) way to let me choose which kind of placement I like for my description list?

Comment: look `enumitem` package. it is very powerful and flexible.

Comment: I second the `enumitem` recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo of the basic description styles defined by enumitem, which can be further customised (font, left margin, &c.):

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin = 12mm}

\begin{document}

‘Force next line’: 
\begin{description}[labelwidth=\textwidth]
\item[One] \lipsum[4]
\item[And another one] \lipsum[4]
\end{description}

With \verb|style=sameline|:
\newlength{\mylength}
\begin{description}[style = sameline]
\item[One] \lipsum[4]
\item[And another one] \lipsum[4]
\end{description}

\newpage

With \verb|style=nextline, font=\itshape|:
\begin{description}[style =nextline, font=\normalfont\itshape]
\item[One] \lipsum[4]
\item[And another one] \lipsum[4]
\end{description}
With \verb|style=multiline, leftmargin=25mm|:
\begin{description}[style=multiline, leftmargin =25mm, font=\sffamily\color{Tomato}]
\item[One] \lipsum[4]
\item[And another one] \lipsum[4]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What about always-force-next-line? Is that supported?

Comment: It is not pre-defined, but easy to obtain. Please see my updated answer.